# *args attribute in the middle of parameters

Tags: python, args

I'm researching the effect of using *args in between a python function but I don't understand if the use case is practical or even possible, it is marked as error on my IDE.

```
def my_function(a, *args, b):
print(a)
print(args)
print(b)


my_function(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

My output is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/axel_/PycharmProjects/Python_Subject_Exam/3_new_exam_args_in_middle.py", line 10, in <module>
    my_function(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
TypeError: my_function() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'b'
```

So, the *args must be ever at the end of parameters of any function, puting it at the midle is invalid python code right?

I also tested it at the end as intended:

```
def my_function(a, b, *args):
    print(a)
    print(args)
    print(b)


my_function(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Output:

```
1
(3, 4, 5)
2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern is used to force users to specify all parameters after `*args`, in your case you *must* set `b`. This would be accepted:

```
my_function(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, b=6)
```